# Regex does not remove the special chars in split function

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am using a regex to split a string into an array of substrings

Input: `mark bill #special# #special method# johni`

```
import re
re.split('[ #, #]+', 'mark bill #special# #special method# johni')
```

When I execute this command the result is: `['mark', 'bill', 'special', 'special method' 'johni']`

That's right, but in string `'special'` I don't want to remove the special chars `#`

I want this result:: `['mark', 'bill', '#special#', #special method#, 'johni']`

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: btw, if you want to test your regex, http://pythex.org/ is a great tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than `split` you should use `findall`:

```
print re.findall(r'#[^#]*#|\S+', 'mark bill #special# #special method# johni')
```

**Output:**

```
['mark', 'bill', '#special#', '#special method#', 'johni']
```